R: Case when seems to execute all conditions
let's say i have this dummy data
df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 4), value = c(-3, 0, 2, NA, NA))

Now, i want to use a case_when logic in a way so that if an id group only has NA values, 0 is returned, if not, then the max value is returned.
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(v_max = case_when(all(is.na(value)) ~ 0,
                                                 TRUE ~ max(value, na.rm = TRUE)))

     id value v_max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    -3     2
2     1     0     2
3     1     2     2
4     4    NA     0
5     4    NA     0

The code works as intended! However, what i receive is a warning:
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `v_max = case_when(all(is.na(value)) ~ 0, TRUE ~ max(value, na.rm = TRUE))`.
ℹ In group 2: `id = 4`.
Caused by warning in `max()`:
! no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

This warning suggests that the values for group id 4 are also forwarded to the max(value, na.rm = TRUE) and because only NA values are found the warning is thrown. However, my understanding of the case_when is that after one criteria is met, in this case all(is.na(value)) the other conditions are not checked.
Could someone explain this behavior? Why are the values of group 4 forwarded to the max operation?
